# Allow access to page with an Admin email address Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Im using Devise gem and Rails to create a web app, and have it set up running correctly, How can I set it up so there is a certain email address which is allowed to access a page.
For example if I login with email@testing.com, only then can I access a certain page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 user roles and permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272911/rails-4-user-roles-and-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this gem https://github.com/ryanb/cancan upto rails 3, but i think its not supporting in rails 4, https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan for greater version OR you can use your own logic