# What's the best way to implement roles in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, roles

I remember a long time ago I was using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan), but as is possible to see from their Github, it hasn't been touched for more than two years.

What's the best approach now, in 2015, to implement different user roles?
What I actually need - I have a system where are users and admins. And I need to have different roles for admins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 user roles and permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272911/rails-4-user-roles-and-permissions)

Comment: This seems like it's really opinion based to me

Answer (score 3):

For **creating user Roles** and managing them (add/delete/search) you can use [Rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and for **authorizing** these roles from your **controllers** you can use [pundit gem](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) because it's more organized than cancancan(Rails 4 version of cancan)